# How to refer to oneself in a ForeignKeyField?

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models, peewee

I'm trying to create a foreignkey that refers to another object in the same model.

```
from peewee import *

class Domain(Model):
    owner = CharField(max_length=40)
    resolves_to = CharField(max_length=40)
    name = CharField(max_length=26)
    last_renewal = IntegerField(null=True) # null=True means that it is optional
    ending_date = IntegerField()
    active = BooleanField()
    parent = ForeignKeyField(Domain, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "domain"
```

But I get an error that Domain is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the string literal **`'self'`**, as is specified in the [documentation on **`ForeignKey`s**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> To create a recursive relationship – an object that has a **many-to-one relationship with itself** – use `models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.

You thus can implement this with:

```
from django.db import models

class Domain(models.Model):
    # …
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'domain'
```